# How to make gradle not to mark build failed if no tests are found

Tags: gradle

As the title says, how can I make gradle not to fail a test task if no tests are found? I ran into this problem when I was using the `--tests` command line option with a multi-subproject project. For instance, this command below will run all tests in class FooTest from subproject A:
`gradle test --tests com.foo.bar.FooTest`

However, this command fails because of something like this:

```
Execution failed for task ':B:test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [com.foo.bar.FooTest]
```

BTW, I know something like below will succeed. But is it possible to make it succeed even with the `test` task? It's kind of annoying to type a test task name longer than `test`.

`gradle :A:test --tests com.foo.bar.FooTest`

Comment: Maybe You can disable this particular task? `project(':B').tasks.test.enabled = false`

Comment: I encountered the same problem, but did not find a solution.  Gradle does have a forum for suggesting new features at http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/ideas/popular, maybe a suggestion could be made to allow suppressing failures in this situation?  It doesn't fix your problem now, but at least there's a chance of something being implemented later.

Answer (score 10):

The behavior you described is the current Gradle behavior, there is already a ticket on Gradle forum, see https://discuss.gradle.org/t/multi-module-build-fails-with-tests-filter/25835

Based on the solution described in this ticket, you can do something like that to disable the 'failIfNoTest' default behavior:

In your root project build (or better: in an [InitScript](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#sec:using_an_init_script)  in your Gradle USER_HOME dir, to make this behavior available for all your local projects)

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    subprojects {
        // TODO: filter projects that does not have test task...
        test {
            filter {
                setFailOnNoMatchingTests(false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can execute the following command without having errors if the given test doesn't exist in all sub-projects:

```
gradle test --tests com.foo.bar.FooTest
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems that currently only a workaround like this is possible:

```
test {
    afterSuite { desc, result ->
        if (!desc.parent) {
            if (result.testCount == 0) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("No tests were found. Failing the build")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have filed an issue with Gradle to introduce this as a simple config option: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/7452

Comment: although this actually answers the opposite of what this question asked, it's still useful. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can also run the tests only for the current project with

```
gradle :test --tests com.foo.bar.FooTest
```

Note the colon before the test task.